# R Shiny: how to automatically start download when output changes

Tags: r, shiny, download

I want to generate data and download it automatically. I have created a "Generate Data" button. It's expected that as I click this button, it will generate data and auto click the "Download" button, so the generated data will be downloaded automatically.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyalert)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  useShinyalert(), 
  actionButton("gener.data", "Generate Data"),
  downloadButton("downloadData")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$gener.data, {

    test_data = data.frame( No=c(1,2,3),Name=c("R","RR","RRR") )
    test_data2 = data.frame( No=c(3,2,1),Name=c("RRR","RR","R") )

    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste("dataset-", ".zip", sep="")
      },
      content = function(file) {
        tmpdir <- tempdir()

        contain_filename <- c( "test.csv", "test2.rds"  )
        write.csv( test_data ,  contain_filename[1] )
        saveRDS( test_data2,  contain_filename[2] )  

        zip(zipfile=file, files=  contain_filename  )

      },contentType = "application/zip"
    )

    #auto click the downloadData button
    runjs("$('#downloadData')[0].click();")

    #show message
    shinyalert(
      title = 'Compelete!',type='success',
      confirmButtonText = "OK"
    )


  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In fact when I click the "Generate Data" button, it downloads html file, not the expected data. It seems js code is executed before the output data is generated.

How can I auto click the "Download Data" after output is generated? Or how can I auto click "Download Data" as soon as output changes?